# Using BackgroundWorker with ProgressBar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls, backgroundworker

Hi i have an App where one of the jobs will be convert an Excel and pass all the records to the DB.

So this takes a little time because it's more than 7000 rows that i will get and insert into the DB.

So because this job takes a little time, more than 3 minutes, I'd like to use a ProgressBar to report progress of this job.

So if i am doing this Job in Class that i have created, how can i use the backgroundWorker to report the progress to the progessBar in my case?

My objective is be accurate in the percentage of how the progress is going, and how i can use all this stuff to report the progress. I have never worked with backgroundWorkers.

I think, and this is only a tip, maybe good or not, that i first get the number of rows in the excel, make that number as some Maxvalue in the ProgressBar, and then for each Row or in an interval i report the progress.

This is possible? How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use bindings for ProgressBars (and pretty much everything else where possible) because that way you do not need to worry about [dispatching to the UI thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).

Basically you create some class that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) with a progress property that you can bind your ProgressBar to. e.g.

```
public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _progress = 0;
    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        private set
        {
            if (_progress != value)
            {
                _progress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
            }
        }
    }

    public Task(ref ProgressChangedEventHandler progressChangedEvent)
    {
        progressChangedEvent += (s, e) => Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This class uses an event in the constructor which will update the Task's progress if raised but you can handle the Progress change in any way you like, e.g. a method or by making the Progress property `public` so you can just change it arbitrarily.

---

Usage example:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="20"
             Value="{Binding UpdateTask.Progress, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

```
// The event that should be raised when a progress occurs.
private event ProgressChangedEventHandler UpdateProgressChanged;

// The task the ProgressBar binds to.
private readonly Task _updateTask;
public Task UpdateTask
{
    get { return _updateTask; }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    // Instatiate task, hooking it up to the update event.
    _updateTask = new Task(ref UpdateProgressChanged);
}

private void OnUpdateProgressChanged(int progressPercentage)
{
    if (UpdateProgressChanged != null)
    {
        UpdateProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, null));
    }
}

// Simple progress simulation
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int progress = 0;
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5) };
    timer.Tick += (sSub,eSub) =>
    {
        progress++;
        // Raise progress changed event which in turn will change
        // the progress of the task which in turn will cause
        // the binding to update which in turn causes the value
        // of the ProgressBar to change.
        OnUpdateProgressChanged(progress);
        if (progress == 100)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Ok i if want to bind the progress of what i am doing here to the progressbar, i use the property Progress, right? Can you give an example of binding the progressbar to this property?

Comment: Added an example, also fixed an error in the task class, the costructor needs to get the event by reference  (`ref` keyword).

Comment: Maybe your [binding is broken](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+wpf+bindings), i tested this and it does work.

Comment: OK, i have created a new wPF App project and picked up your example here, and tested it, and to discover if the value is being update in the progBar, in the end of the OnUpdatedProgressChanged method, i used a messageBox to show me the value of the progressbar every time the progress property is incremented, and the value just don't change. It's always 0, but the property is being incremented...

Comment: Did you make the change to the `Task` class which needs to have the event passed by reference?

Comment: As i said before, **[does the binding work](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+wpf+bindings)**, are there any errors in the Output window? My code is **not complete**, i bind utilizing the DataContext. If are not that familiar with binding [read the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: When he tries the binding he report some warnings in the Output Window, like he's trying to bind to the property but like for any reason he can't.

Comment: Seriously, gawd damn, **it is not supposed to work just like that** as i said before, **the code is not complete**, can you see me setting any DataContext anywhere? No, you can't. Can one use a binding that only specifies a path without a DataContext? **No, you can't.** **[Read about DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)**, **now**.

Comment: So if i use the DataContext and then bind the progressBar to the DataContext it works? Anyway, i already have used DataContext with other things but i don't know much about it. I quit from using them when i discover that DataGridComboBoxColumn doesn't have a DataContext. So, in this cases, i send the DataContext from the progBar, the one from the parent, or the one from the Window?

Comment: The DataContext needs to be set to whatever object that contains the `Task` as public property. (Also: The **DataContext is important**, the DataGrid is just one single control on the other hand)

Comment: So what i just have to do was this and it's working: `this.DataContext = _updateTask;` in Code Behind, and this in XAML: `<ProgressBar (...) Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}"/>`. But after i will implement this in my case, that is reading records from an Excel file via COM Interop and show the progress of the job, Properties can cause Problems because of being used in different threads? Thanks ;)

Comment: You might want to rename the `Task` Class so folks don't confuse it with `Task` from the framework. Especially since they deal with doing work in the background. As a side, note anyone reading this page may want to look in to using the Tasking built into .net instead of the older, background worker.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a [background worker with progress](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html).

However, double-check to make sure a BGW will work in your situation. If you're controlling Excel via COM interop, it may require an STA thread (and a BGW is an MTA thread, not STA).

If that's the case, you'll need to use a `Task` with an [STA scheduler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx), or your own manual `Thread` (I strongly suggest the `Task`-based approach).

Comment: Yes i am using Com Interop. So the Task approach you are talking about is the one referred in the backgroudn worker with progress link, right?

Comment: Yes, except you'll have to use the `StaTaskScheduler` that I linked to.