# How to Add a progress bar when user trying to start/stop windows service

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, progress-bar

```
`private void btnStartServerIns_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("RMExSoftphoneService");
            if ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)))
            {
                sc.Start();

                LogDebug("Starting the  RMExSoftphoneServer");
            }               
            LogDebug("Started the RMExSoftphoneServer");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            LogDebug(Ex.Message);   
        }
    }`
```

I have a project which starts and stops a service. Most of the times it is fast but sometimes it is not. so i want to way to show the user that is function is being executed

Comment: Have you tried a ProgressBar?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774473/using-backgroundworker-with-progressbar-in-wpf

Comment: Use a background thread (i.e. `BackgroundWorker`).